# vertical-align: middle not working as expected

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

`vertical-align: middle` is not working as expected.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

The above link says this:

> The element is placed in the middle of the parent element

However, in the below link, `"world"` is not placed in the middle of the parent element.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/og08vdfa/)

```css
.hello {
  font-size: 32px;
  background-color: hotpink;
}

.world {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: lime;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<p><span class="hello">Hello</span> <span class="world">world</span></p>
```

Comment: for what it have to be center.  . if there is a parent element for that, can set the child element center  to its parent element

Comment: If you want to align the text in the middle then that's not going to work.

Comment: The text on the W3Schools page is so short as to be misleading. If only they had spent a few words more to explain. And the "Play it" example is not very helpful either.

Answer (score 1):

your first span size is bigger than other span. So p tag size change according to the bigger span. Because of that I have to applied veritical-align: middle on both the span

```
 .hello {
   font-size: 32px;
   background-color: hotpink;
 }

p span {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: lime;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: when you add vertical-align css on world class. How it suppose to understand which is middle point. give the some height to its parents tag.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to have `span` inside a `span`. It says,

> The element is placed in the middle of the parent element

So, it has to be inside your parent element, which in this case, I understand is `span`. Unless, you considering `p` as the parent, in that case, you can move `class="hello"` to `p` tag.

```css
p {
  background-color: orange;
}
.hello {
  font-size: 32px;
  background-color: hotpink;
}

.world {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: lime;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<p><span class="hello">Hello <span class="world">world</span></span>
</p>
```

Comment: I'm curious why `"world"` isn't centered with respect to the `<p>` tag.

Comment: Well, you can use `display: table-cell;` to get it centered.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.hello {
  font-size: 32px;
  background-color: hotpink;
}
span{
  
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: lime;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<p><span class="hello">Hello</span> <span>world</span></p>

</body>
</html>
```